# Solitaire with cards triplets which sum to 9,19 or 29?

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

My Dad taught me the following solitaire game:

- **Deal**: remove all face cards, putting down 5 rows.
- **Play**: one card at a time, try to get 3 cards to a total of `9`, `19`, or `29`. If they do, discard them and keep going through the deck, reusing the discard pile when needed, with out shuffling.
- **Game ends:** when all cards are in the discard pile. The last card is always a 3.
- **Score**: if you win, you take the discard pile, draw 5 cards at a time and that's where I forget how to score.

Does anyone know the name and how to score?